# How do I find a specific bug on Apple's Bug Reporter?

Tags: bug, applecare

Apple's [Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/) site sometimes provides numbers of related or duplicate bugs, but I see no way to locate the referred-to bug, and the search feature only searches bugs that I've submitted.

How do I find a specific bug, not submitted by me, (e.g., using the bug number) on Apple's Bug Reporter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apple's bug database is private, and as you see, you are only able to review the bugs that you submit. This has been the subject of much debate in the Apple developer community.

[Open Radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/) is an attempt to shed light on bugs that participating developers file. It uses the same ID numbers as the real Bug Reporter system, so if the bug referred to is in Open Radar, you should be able to find it by its ID.

Comment: So if I report a bug (say, [3 years ago](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/60221/4395)) and Apple says it's a duplicate, and the bug is still happening, there's no way to find out what Apple is doing (or not doing) about it (if it [doesn't show up](http://openradar.appspot.com/search?query=6056296) in Open Radar)?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: So I guess I need to submit a feature request abut the bug database!

Comment: You could, but given how long Apple has been aware of the developer community's...discontent...with the status quo, I wouldn't hold my breath on a positive response. Open Radar was started in 2008, for example.

Comment: I wasn't going to go there, but — yes, unless something draws in new customers (or is enough to drive away existing ones), I don't thing Apple has the slightest interest in addressing it.